# How to select lines with the values in range?

Tags: shell, awk

I have 70 files and I would like to print from each files those lines that have column $1 between two values. How to do that please?

```
awk ' for (i = 1; i <= 70; i++) ($1>=4760 && $1<=5000){print}' file000"$i".asc > fileout000"$i"
```

Comment: Though reasonably clear, when asking questions related to extractions from tablular/csv data, it is a good idea to include 10-15 lines of representative data in your question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk variables can't be seen from shell, you need to do the redirection internally, like:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {
  close(fname)
  fname=("out_" FILENAME)
}
($1>=4760 && $1<=5000) {
  print > fname
}' file000*.asc
```